# Меняется значение event.keyCode клавиш "w,a,s,d", и функции вызываются несколько раз в <body onkeypress="">

Tags: javascript, html

1. Коды клавиш wasd:
     var KEY_CODE =
     {
       LEFT: 97,
       UP: 119,
       RIGHT:100 ,
       DOWN: 115
     };
   После простоя страницы коды меняются на:
   1099,1094,1092... могут поменятся обратно.
   (Смотрю значения в console)
2. При каждом последующем нажатии функция на событие, event.keypress вызывается столько раз, сколько была нажата клавиша 0_о. 
   Код:

```js
function Move()
{
  addEventListener("keypress",
  function()
    {
      console.log(event.keyCode);

      var KEY_CODE =
      {
        LEFT: 97,
        UP: 119,
        RIGHT:100 ,
        DOWN: 115
      };
      step=2;

      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case KEY_CODE.RIGHT:
        Right();
          break;
          case KEY_CODE.LEFT:
          Left();
            break;
            case KEY_CODE.UP:
              Up();
              break;
              case KEY_CODE.DOWN:
              Down();
                break;
        default:

      }
    });

}
function Left()
{
  element = document.getElementById('portrait');
  left = window.getComputedStyle(element).left;
  value=left.substring(0,left.length-2);
  console.log("left "+value+" step"+step);
  value=parseInt(value)-step;
  console.log("value=parseInt(value)-step;"+value);
  value+="px";
  console.log("value+px  "+value);
  document.getElementById('portrait').style.left=value;
  console.log("  document.getElementById('portrait')="+document.getElementById('portrait').style.left);
}
function Right()
{
  element = document.getElementById('portrait');
  left = window.getComputedStyle(element).left;
  value=left.substring(0,left.length-2);
  value=parseInt(value)+step;
  value+="px";
  document.getElementById('portrait').style.left=value;
}
function Up()
{
  element = document.getElementById('portrait');
  up = window.getComputedStyle(element).top;
  value=up.substring(0,up.length-2);
  value=parseInt(value)-step;
  value+="px";
  document.getElementById('portrait').style.top=value;
}
function Down()
{
  element = document.getElementById('portrait');
  down = window.getComputedStyle(element).top;
  value=down.substring(0,down.length-2);
  value=parseInt(value)+step;
  value+="px";
  document.getElementById('portrait').style.top=value;
}
```

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
#portrait {
   position: absolute;
   left: 300px;
   top:200px;
   width: 48px;
   height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="elements.css">
</head>
<body onkeypress="Move()">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 <script src="move.js"></script>
  <div id="portrait" class="portrait">
    <img src="img/illuminatygas.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**По поводу пляшущих значений**

В *JavaScript* события для `OnKeyPress` и `OnKeyDown/OnKeyUp` немного отличаются друг от друга при обработке. В частности, функция `OnKeyPress` в объекте `KeyboardEvent` передает в значениях `charCode` и `keyCode` одно и то же значение равное коду символа (а не клавиши). То есть в обоих значениях получается `charCode`, поэтому у Вас и пляшут значения при смене раскладки клавиатуры, а не из-за простоя.

Что бы отследить реальный `charCode` используйте события `OnKeyDown/OnKeyUp` для обработчика.

**По поводу вашего многократного keypress**

Вы в коде вешаете на `body` обработчик нажатия клавиши `<body onkeypress="Move()">`, который срабатывает каждый раз и каждый раз вызывается функция `Move`, в которой снова вешается еще один обработчик `addEventListener("keypress", ...)`. В итоге они у Вас накапливаются и каждый раз все вместе вызываются.